# C++ exception in cv::BFMatcher

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, matching, opencv-features2d

I am having problems with the cv::BFMatcher when I try to perform the feature matching. I compute the descriptors with the xfeatures2D::SIFT descriptor. When I try to perform the matching the application output shows "Exception at 0x7ff833308b9c, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\xthrow.cpp:13"
The code is something like:

```
matchesltor.clear();
matchesrtol.clear();

cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_L2);

ProcessedImageData *imageDataLeft = mImageDataMap.value(mapKeyList.at(m));
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> tiePointsLeft = imageDataLeft->getTiepoints();
cv::Mat descriptorsLeft= imageDataLeft->getDescriptors();
ProcessedImageData *imageDataRight = mImageDataMap.value(mapKeyList.at(n));
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> tiePointsRight = imageDataRight->getTiepoints();
cv::Mat descriptorsRight= imageDataRight->getDescriptors();

matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsLeft,descriptorsRight,matchesltor,2)
matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsRight,descriptorsLeft,matchesrtol,2)
```

The output message is shown in the firts line that performs the matching "matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsLeft,descriptorsRight,matchesltor,2)".

The strange thing is that it work in a single qt project that only perform the tie point detection, tie point description and matching but when I try to join it in other project (same code, same compiler and same qt version) it shows that output message and the execution stop (the application does not break).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why did you not debug it? Run a debug build under the debugger and see where it crashes. Add the call stack to your question.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to say that the output message is showed in the line that perform the feature matching "matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsLeft,descriptorsRight,matchesltor,2)". I debug the appliation and the only message that it shows is "Exception at 0x7ff833308b9c, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\xthrow.cpp:13".

Comment: Don't comment - edit the question. And **add the call stack** from when it crashed.